# How many types of mining pool are exist for bitcoin or litecoin?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-software

I would like to know exactly how is the type of different Bitcoin or litecoin pool ?!

For example when you have P2POOL , it can be getwork or stratum but they are protocol ?!

In some pool like BTCGuild when you mine, the reward will be added instantly but in P2POOL takes time to see the reward in you wallet.

Comment: Most pools are centrally managed - have managed servers to which the miners connect to pool resources. P2Pool, instead, is a decentralized type of pool - it has no central manager so theoretically you need to place no trut on anyone. Te downside is you don't get paid unless such pool finds a block as opposed to the others which can pay from the pool's owners coins whilst the pool finds a block.

Answer (score 2):

The pools are mostly distinguished by:

- fees: how much the pool charges workers
- size: the larger the pool, the smaller the variance of your payouts
- payout style: pay per share, pay per last N shares, etc.
- location: do they have a server near you (extra latency will mean less mining work accepted and a lower payout)

As you guessed, getwork, long poll, stratum, etc. are not types of pools, but rather types of protocols for getting mining work from the pools. Some pools support more than one type of protocol.

You can see a nice comparison of various BTC mining pools here:
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Comparison_of_mining_pools